# How can one get the name of an HDF5 DataSet through the C or C++ API?

Tags: c++, hdf5

I'm trying to read the name of a HDF5 DataSet using the C++ API. For `H5::Attribute` objects, there is a `getName()` method.  However, I don't see a similar `getName()` method for `H5:DataSet` objects.

Ideally I want to do this:

```
 void Dump(H5::DataSet& ds)
 {
    cout << "Dataset " << ds.getName() << endl;
    // continue to print dataset values
 }
```

I know `h5dump` can do it, but briefly looking at the code, it only knows it by walking the tree using `H5Giterate`, that is only the parent knows the name of the children, but the children don't know their own name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, there is [`H5Iget_name`](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5I.html#Identify-GetName). I couldn't find the equivalent in C++ but you can use [`DataSet::getId()`](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/cpplus_RM/classH5_1_1DataSet.html#aa0b5b0136755eecf6ec4aa498d1da3ec) and give that to the C function.

I guess the reason why this is not as simple as having a `getName()` accessor in `DataSet` is that to read a dataset, you either need to know its name or walk the tree. The only exception I can think of is when dereferencing a reference to a dataset.

Answer (score 6):

This is a partial answer, based on Simon's post. Note that the name is a full hierarchical name,

```
std::string getName(const H5::DataSet& ds)
{
    size_t len = H5Iget_name(ds.getId(),NULL,0);
    char buffer[len];
    H5Iget_name(ds.getId(),buffer,len+1);
    std::string n = buffer;
    return n;
}
```

example name

```
"/toplevel/videodata"
```