# Given a H5::Group, how do I print its full path within its hdf5 file?

Tags: c++, hdf5

I have some code that takes some random H5::Group. My understanding is that from this object, I should be able to learn what file it is in and what the path to it is within that file.

```
void PrintPathTo(const H5::Group& group){
std::stringstream path;
path << group.getFileName() << ":/" << group.getPath() // this doesn't work. Is there something like it?

std::cout << path.str() << std::endl; 


}
```

Is this possible without searching the whole file?

Comment: `group.FileName()` is ok I guess however for the path you should see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22798731/how-can-one-get-the-name-of-an-hdf5-dataset-through-the-c-or-c-api it deals with dataset be the same can be applied to group